# Is update in place possible in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli, nosql

I have a table in Cassandra where I populate some rows with 1000s of entries (each row is with 10000+ columns). The entries in the rows are very frequently updated, basically just a field (which is an integer) is updated with different values. All other values for the columns remains unmodified. My question is, will the updates be done in-place ? How good is Cassandra for frequent update of entries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially these updates are stored in an in-memory data structure called Memtable. Memtables are flushed to immutable SSTables at regular intervals.

So a single wide row will be read from various SSTables. It is during a process called 'compacation' the different SSTables will be merged into a bigger SSTable on the disk.

Increasing thresholds for flushing Memtables is one way of optimization. If updates are coming very fast before Memtable is flushed to disk, i think that update should be in-place in memory, not sure though.

Also each read operation checks Memtables first, if data is still there, it will be simply returned – this is the fastest possible access.

Cassandra [read path](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_read_path_c.html):

`When a read request for a row comes in to a node, the row must be combined from all SSTables on that node that contain columns from the row in question`

Cassandra [write path:](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html)

Comment: So, what happens to a record that was updated. There may be one copy in an already created SSTable file. And hence the same record may be on multiple SSTable files. Also, how the records are kept sorted across multiple SSTable files ?

Comment: For the cases where record is stored in multiple SSTables, it will be read from SSTable with most recent modification time.

Comment: Does that mean it will need scanning across all the SSTable files for read of a record from some row ?

Comment: If the partition's data is spread across multiple SSTables, then yes, multiple SSTables will be accessed during a read.

Comment: @John All SSTables that contain the partition's data will be accessed. It's the intra-node merge process that checks the timestamp for each cell and then combines all cells into a single partition before sending the response to the coordinator.

Answer (score 6):

First of all every update is also a sequential write for cassandra so, as far as cassandra goes it does not make any difference to cassandra whether you update or write.

The real question is how fast do you need to read those writes to be available for reading? As @john suggested, first all the writes are written to a mutable CQL Memtable which resides in memory. So, every update is essentially appended as a new sequential entry to memtable for a particular CQL table. It is concurrently periodically also written to `commitlog' (every 10 seconds) for durability.

When Memtable is full or total size for comittlog is reached, cassandra flushes all the data to immutable Sorted String Table (SSTable). After the flush, compaction is the procedure where all the PK entries for the new column values are kept and all the previous values (before update) are removed.

With flushing frequently comes the overhead on frequent sequential writes to disk and compaction which could take lot of I/O and have a serious impact on cassandra performance.

As far as read goes, first cassandra will try to read from `row cache` (if its enabled) or from `memtable`. If it fails there it will go to `bloom filter`, `key cache`, `partition summary`, `partition index` and finally to SSTable in that order. When the data is collected for all the column values, its aggregate in memory and the column values with latest timestamp are returned to client after aggregation and an entry is made in `row cache` for that partition key`.

So, yes when you query a partition key, it will scan across all the SSTable for that particular CQL table and the memtable for all the column values that are not being flushed to disk yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, in place updates are not possible.

As @john suggested, if you have frequent writes then you should delay the flush process. During the flush, the multiple writes to the same partition that are stored in the MemTable will be written as a single partition in the newly created SSTable.

C* is fine for heavy writes. However, you'll need to monitor the number of SSTables accessed per read. If the # is too high, then you'll need to review your compaction strategy.